# images appear stacked as column instead of as a row

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS rule:

```
.list_meta {
font-size: 10px;
line-height: 18px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
color: 
#999;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: block;
}
```

I have a set of star images which I want to appear as `*****`
Instead, they appear as:

```
*
*
*
*
*
```

The code I'm trying is:

```
<span class="list_meta">
   <span style="float:left; padding-right:10px; display: inline;">
      <img src="small_star.png" alt="Star" height="9" width="10">
      <img src="small_star.png" alt="Star" height="9" width="10">
   </span>
5 Star Rating</span>
```

I want to achieve `***** 5 Star Rating`
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hi it's work check to live http://tinkerbin.com/OJTTRXKA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
.list_meta img{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the images inside a `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use a list instead of a load of `<div>`'s / `<span>`'s - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/fk2zL/

**css code:**

```
li {
   float: left;
   list-style: none;
   padding-right:10px; 
}
```

**html code:**

```
<ul>
    <li>*</li>
    <li>*</li>
    <li>*</li>
    <li>*</li>
    <li>*</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

apply these `style="float:left; padding-right:10px; display: inline;"` style on each image instead of using it on `span`

**CSS:**

```
span img {float:left; padding-right:10px; display: inline;}​
```

**HTML:**

```
<span class="list_meta">
   <span>
      <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/diagona/icon/16/031.png" alt="Star" height="9" width="10">
      <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/diagona/icon/16/031.png" alt="Star" height="9" width="10">
   </span>
5 Star Rating
</span>​
```

[**SEE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/h6qCF/)